# Use dynamic properties using Dropwizard,Hystrix and Archaius

Tags: dropwizard, hystrix

I am trying to use Dropwizard with Hystrix and Archaius using the yml file from DropWizard.I need to change Archaius property file values dynamically at runtime. How do I do that ? I have looked at the following links and am able to get key value data from YML property files by extending the Configuration class and passing it into the Application sub-class :
http://christopher-batey.blogspot.com/2014/08/using-hystrix-with-dropwizard.html

I want to use Archaius to configure these property values dynamically at runtime. How can I do that ?
Using Tenacity with Breakerbox is overkill for what I need.
The article above refers to this :"Then later extend the Configuration you install to include a dynamic configuration source such as ZooKeeper."-how to do that without using Zookeeper as long as I can just change a property file and have Hystrix pick up the change.

TIA,
Vijay

Comment: One more way to change configuration dynamically is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35712393/netflix-archaius-dynamic-configuration)

Answer (score 2):

Dropwizard will read the YAML file once at startup. Changes at runtime in the YAML file will not work in the example given above.

The **simplest thing** that could work for you is described in the [Getting Started](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/wiki/Getting-Started):

Skip the configuration via YAML completely, remove the `ConfigurationManager.install()` part, put the runtime configuration in a separate Java properties file, and specify the `archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls` system parameter. Your command line for dropwizard would look like this:

```
java -Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=file:///apps/myapp/application.properties -jar mydropwizard.jar server config.yml
```

As stated in the documentation, the URL can be on the web, or a local file.

In a more elaborate solution you could specify the URL in you YAML file and create a DynamicURLConfiguration with the URL you receive form the YAML file.

Best regards,
Alexander.