# Netflix Archaius Dynamic Configuration

Tags: java, hystrix, netflix-archaius

I am integrating Hystrix in to my existing project and I want to read the configuration values from an xml file instead of feeding the configuration properties using Configuration Manager. When the values are updated in the xml file I want Hystrix configuration to be updated at runtime.

This is the guide I am following: 
https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/wiki/Users-Guide

I understand so far that I can use PolledConfigurationSource and the following code:

```
PolledConfigurationSource source = ...
AbstractPollingScheduler scheduler = ...
DynamicConfiguration configuration = new DynamicConfiguration(source, scheduler);
ConfigurationManager.install(configuration);
```

How do I point PolledConfigurationSource to an xml file to read the properties after a fixed time interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code did the trick for me

```
private void initializeConfiguration() {

    // FixedDelayPollingScheduler is initialized with default system
    // settings
    // Fixed delay in milliseconds between two reads of the configuration
    // URLs
    // archaius.fixedDelayPollingScheduler.delayMills = 60000
    // Initial delay in milliseconds of reading from the configuration
    // source
    // archaius.fixedDelayPollingScheduler.initialDelayMills = 30000
    AbstractPollingScheduler scheduler = new FixedDelayPollingScheduler();

    // Configuration source that brings dynamic changes to the configuration
    // via polling
    PolledConfigurationSource source = new XMLPolledConfigurationSource();

    // Configuration that polls a PolledConfigurationSource according to the
    // schedule set by a scheduler
    DynamicConfiguration configuration = new DynamicConfiguration(source, scheduler);

    ConfigurationManager.install(configuration);

    // Registering configuration with an MBean and will be accessible for
    // read and update via JConsole
    ConfigJMXManager.registerConfigMbean(configuration);
}
```

XMLPolledConfigurationSource source code

```
public class XMLPolledConfigurationSource implements PolledConfigurationSource {

@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
public PollResult poll(boolean inital, Object checkPoint) throws Exception {
    PollResult pollResult = null;
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    // Code to read content from the resource
    return pollResult.createFull(map);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using setting this system variable as per documentation?

`-Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls=file:///apps/myapp/application.xml`

By documentation I am referring to the Getting started web page https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: Hmm, how can I set -Darchaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls to an xml file in src/main/resource folder?

Comment: Apart from that, was anybody able to to use PolledConfigurationSource? 

As suggested in the guide, I will extend PolledConfigurationSource class and use StAX parser to read content from the file, put them in a HashMap and set PollResult.createFull(map);

Comment: You pass it as a parameter when you run the java application and use only the file name, it will resolve its path in the classpath... If it's a self executable jar you would do it like so `java -jar myapp.jar -Darchaius...=config.xml`. Should work according to documentation

Comment: I tried additionalUrls approach but sadly Hystrix is not picking up the file. I think I will try the approach I mentioned in the previous comment.